# Passing Input Text to Dynamic Text in Flash AS2

Tags: flash, dynamic, text, input, actionscript-2

I haven't done a lot of ActionScript in my day, so any help on this would be great.

I'm trying to pass 2 Input Texts to 2 Dynamic Texts:

- line1 ---> result1
- line2 ---> result2

My problem is, I'm trying to keep the result1 and result2 with different fonts, colors, etc. But when I set different fonts for the results, it also changes the fonts of the inputs.

I know it's probably a simple fix, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

```
line1.onChanged = function(tf_txt1:TextField) {
result1.text = tf_txt1.text;
};
line2.onChanged = function(tf_txt2:TextField) {
result2.text = tf_txt2.text;
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Aaron

Comment: How are you changing the fonts?  And what is the code you use for creating/instantiating the `TextFields`?

Comment: I'm changing the fonts by actually clicking the "Dynamic Text" field on the Flash stage and changing the font/color properties, but this changes the "Input Text" field font/color at runtime also.

Comment: Can you send me a sample FLA? I cannot tell anything from this info -- seems like it should be ok, but apparently it's not. Send to my junk email: testdee@yahoo.com

Comment: You may want to check out styling your as2 with css? http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50130-formatting-with-css-in-actionscript/